# AWS: how to schedule deleting EBS Snapshots after 1 week?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, cloudwatch

I'm scheduled automatic creation EBS Snapshots using CloudWatch
How to schedule automatic deleting old snapshots?

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help. It's a Python program I wrote that takes snapshots of all volumes and keeps the last 2 snapshots.

You could run a program like this on an EC2 instance, or convert it to run as a scheduled AWS Lambda function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto.ec2, os

MAX_SNAPSHOTS = 2   # Number of snapshots to keep

# Connect to EC2 in this region
connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('<insert region here>')

# Get a list of all volumes
volumes = connection.get_all_volumes()

# Create a snapshot of each volume
for v in volumes:
  connection.create_snapshot(v.id)

  # Too many snapshots?
  snapshots = v.snapshots()
  if len(snapshots) > MAX_SNAPSHOTS:

    # Delete oldest snapshots, but keep MAX_SNAPSHOTS available
    snap_sorted = sorted([(s.id, s.start_time) for s in snapshots], key=lambda k: k[1])
    for s in snap_sorted[:-MAX_SNAPSHOTS]:
      print "Deleting snapshot", s[0]
      connection.delete_snapshot(s[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take snapshots and put tags like "DeleteOn:" on those snapshots.

Write another lambda which read snapshots on basis of this tag and delete it on that particular date. There is detailed on this in botocore Doc: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html